# JavaScript date difference Days

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to calculate the difference between two dates. Currently, I am doing the code bellow:

```
function calculDiff(){
    var v1= $('#date_debut').val();
    var v2=$('#date_fin').val();
    var dayDiff=((v2-v1) / (24*60*60*1000));
    var dayDiff2=Math.floor(dayDiff);
    console.log(v1 + ' '+ v2);
    console.log(dayDiff + ' '+ dayDiff2);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date_debut').datepicker().bind('change paste keyup',function(){
        calculDiff();
        return false;
    });
    //
    $('#date_fin').datepicker().bind('change paste keyup',function(){
        calculDiff();
        return false;
    });
});
```

PS:I have 2 input type date (date_debut and date_fin)

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: I have Nan as output, and there is no DateDiff calculation

Comment: In browsers that don't support input type date, what is the value returned by `$('#date_debut').val()`?

Comment: $('#date_debut').val() returns a date that i am choosing from a datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "04/09/2013 14:20:30";
moment.utc(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

See more in
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: thank you very much, but that not what I'm looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I think you want day difference, you can user below code to get days difference.

```
var start_date = new Date($('#date_debut').val());
var end_date = new Date($('#date_fin').val()); 

var diff = new Date(end_date - start_date);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
console.log("diff=>"+days);
```

When user selected first date open other date datepicker to select remaining field, and then calculate difference.

Comment: What I get diff=>NaN

Comment: I have updated my answer please check now, i provided comment if not work then convert into date e.x new Date(value);

Comment: Now It works , thank you very much. But still the Date format , how to foce this format dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: you can change the format in datepicker method { dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }. like $('#date_debut').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. God bless you !