# Formatting dates when getting days between 2 dates with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to calculate the days between 2 dates and it is working as far as I can tell but I keep getting stupidly high numbers which clearly isn't right, I have a feeling this is the way my dates are set out. my dates are set out as dd/mm/yyyy and this is the code I am using:

```
var diff = new Date(end_date - start_date);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
console.log("diff=>"+days);
```

This is the question I used to get the answer:
[JavaScript date difference Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065537/javascript-date-difference-days)

When it writes to the console this is the result I get:

```
diff=>17301.95833332176
```

Comment: Can you show an actual example of it failing? Create a snippet?

Comment: Please show us exactly what your `start_date` and `end_date` look like.

Comment: For the end date i am using `.datepicker("getDate")` to get the date in the format of dd/mm/yyyy and for the start date i am using a php function to get today's date `date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 1, date("d"), date("Y")))`

Answer (score 1):

I have had a play with the code, although I have not used HTML, i set the vars statically below.

```
var end_date = new Date("May 25, 2017");
var start_date = new Date("May 23, 2017");
var diff = new Date(end_date - start_date);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
console.log("diff=>"+days);
```

I have also checked it with a 3 value date format

```
var end_date = new Date(2017,4,25);
var start_date = new Date(2017,4,23);
var diff = new Date(end_date - start_date);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
console.log("diff=>"+days);
```

I manage to get an output of 2. Which is what i expected. The code you supplied looks ok to me. Maybe look at the HTML to check that the values being passed are in the correct format.

Jquery [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) may be of help to you here.

Comment: For the end date i am using `.datepicker("getDate")` to get the date in the format of dd/mm/yyyy and for the start date i am using a php function to get today's date `date("d/m/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 1, date("d"), date("Y")))`

Comment: Do you need to use the PHP? you could use the JS Date.now(); to pass todays date though.

Comment: it was something as simple as that, it was something wrong with the format of the php date that was messing it up, thanks for your help! switching it to date.now() fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, is to use [countBtw](https://github.com/Jimmy02020/aleppo#date_countBtw)

```
var { date } = require('aleppo')
//..
date.countBtw('all', date1, date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use moment: https://momentjs.com

```
var moment = require('moment');

var start_moment = moment(start_date);
var end_moment = moment(end_date);

var days = start_moment.diff(end_moment, 'days');
console.log("diff=>" + days);
```

You can also get weeks, months etc. with this method